# a problem about averages of fractional parts

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I know a little analytic number theory , for example i know that:

$\sum_{d\le x}(\frac{x}{d}-[\frac {x}{d}])=\frac{x}{a}(1-\gamma)+O(\sqrt x)$
when the $\sum$ is over $d$'s the integers less or equal with $x$ that are congruent to $b$ mod $a$ and $\gamma $ is Euler's constant.

how can i prove this?

$$\sum_{p\le x}\left(\frac{x}{p}-\left[\frac {x}{p}\right]\right)=\frac{x}{\log x}(1-\gamma)+o\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$$

it is really important to me,help me please!

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tag{1}\sum_{p\le n}\left(\frac{n}{p}-\left[\frac {n}{p}\right]\right)=\frac{n}{\log n}(1-\gamma)+o\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)\\\text{(the sum is over the primes $p\le n$)}$$

is a result from de la Vallée-Poussin (1898) ["Sur les valeurs moyennes de certaines fonctions  arithmétiques" $(4.)$](https://oeis.org/w/images/a/af/Sur_les_valeurs_moyennes_de_certaines_fonctions_arithm%C3%A9tiques.pdf). Let's translate the part $4.$ for reference...

"The starting point is the well known equality (for $\,\log(n!)\,$ from Legendre with the exponent of $p$ in $n!$ given by $\,\displaystyle\sum_{j>0}\left[\frac n{p^j}\right]$) :
$$\tag{2}\sum_{p\le n} \log(p)\sum_{j>0}\left[\frac n{p^j}\right]=\sum_{k\le n}\log(k)$$
Let's note $\,\displaystyle r(p):=\frac np-\left[\frac np\right]\;$ and $\,\epsilon\to 0$ as $\dfrac 1n\to 0\;$ then (since $\dfrac n{p-1}=\dfrac np+\dfrac n{p^2}+\dfrac n{p^3}+\cdots$) $(2)$ divided by $n$ will give (concluding with Stirling's formula for $\log(n!)$) :
$$\tag{3}\sum_{p\le n} \frac{\log(p)}{p-1}-\frac 1n\sum_{p\le n}\log(p)\,r(p)=\frac 1n\sum_{k\le n}\log(k)+\epsilon_1=\log(n)-1+\epsilon_2$$
but it was shown (in de la Vallée-Poussin's proof of the PNT using the logarithmic derivative of the Euler product) that for $\gamma$ the Euler constant :
$$\tag{4}\sum_{p\le n} \frac{\log(p)}{p-1}=\log(n)-\gamma+\epsilon_3$$
Subtracting $(3)$ from $(4)$ we conclude that 
$$\tag{5}\frac 1n\sum_{p\le n} \log(p)\,r(p)=1-\gamma+\epsilon_4$$
Since the asymptotic number of primes $\le n$ is given by $\,\dfrac n{\log(n)}\,$ from the PNT the mean value of the fractions $r(p)$ will be (for $n$ infinitely large) : 
$$\tag{6} \frac {\log(n)}n \sum_{p\le n} r(p)$$ To prove that $(6)$ will converge to $\,1-\gamma\;$ like the left part of $(5)$ let's compute their difference 
$$\tag{7} \frac {\log(n)}n \sum_{p\le n} r(p)-\frac 1n\sum_{p\le n} \log(p)\,r(p)=\frac 1n\sum_{p\le n} (\log(n)-\log(p))\;r(p)$$
Since $0\le r(p)<1\,$ this will be positive and less than $\,\displaystyle \frac 1n\sum_{p\le n}(\log(n)-\log(p))\,$ which goes to $0$ as will be shown. The number of terms such that $\,p\le n\,$ has the asymptotic expression $\,\displaystyle (1+\epsilon)\frac n{\log(n)}$, further $\,\displaystyle \sum_{p\le n} \log(p)=(1+\epsilon')n\,$
 (as shown in the PNT paper) so that :

$$\tag{8} \frac 1n\sum_{p\le n}(\log(n)-\log(p))=\frac 1n\left[(1+\epsilon)\frac n{\log(n)}\log(n)+(1+\epsilon')n\right]=\epsilon-\epsilon'$$
which goes to $0$ with $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$.

This proves that $\,\displaystyle \frac {\log(n)}n \sum_{p\le n} r(p)=(1-\gamma)+o(1)\,$ and the theorem."

Ref: Friedrich Pillichshammer ["Euler's constant and averages of fractional parts"](http://www.dmg.tuwien.ac.at/nfn/gamma.pdf).

Comment: thank you a lot , but how did you write (3)?

Comment: Glad it helped @user115608. For $(3)$ use simply $\dfrac n{p-1}=\dfrac np+\dfrac n{p^2}+\cdots$.

Comment: i can't understand you from ((Indeed their difference...))

Comment: @user115608: I edited my answer and hope it will be clearer. Fine continuation,

Comment: thanks again!u can't imagine what a great help it was!just two question remain:how do u say (4)?and how about $\Sigma {\log p}=...?$

Comment: 1. De la Vallée Poussin's original (very long) proof may be consulted [here](https://archive.org/stream/recherchesanaly00pousgoog#page/n38) (from $24.$ page 99 to $28.$ p.34, $52.$ p.61, $55.$ p.64 and $57.$ P.69). The idea is to start with $\;\log \zeta(s)=-\sum_p \log\left(1-\frac 1{p^s}\right)$ for $s>1$, differentiate it to get $\displaystyle \,\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}= -\sum_p \frac{\log(p)}{p^s-1}=-\sum_p \frac{\log(p)}{p^s}-\sum_p \frac{\log(p)}{p^{2s}}-\cdots$, use the logarithmic derivative of the functional equation to rewrite this in another way (in $8.$ p.9)...

Comment: make many manipulations to obtain (at the limit $s\to 1$) $$\sum_{p\le y} \frac{\log(p)}{p-1}-\frac 1y\sum_{p\le y}\log(p)=\log(y)-1-\lim_{s\to 1}\left[\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac 1{s-1}\right]+\epsilon$$ 
The limit of the [ ] term will be $\gamma$ because $\zeta(1+e)=1/e+\gamma+O(e)\,$ from the Stieltjes expansion while $ \frac 1y\sum_{p\le y}\log(p)$ goes to $1$ (your question 2.) getting thus $(4)$.$$-$$ 
2. de la Vallée Poussin proved that the [PNT was equivalent to $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {\theta(n)}n=1\,$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement)

Comment: with $\,\theta(n):=\sum_{p\le n}\log(p)\;$ the first [Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function)...  Perhaps that the proof from the reference at the end will be simpler after all!

Comment: can u explain more about (4)?write it as an answer please

Comment: @user115608: the answer to $(4)$ is a good part of de la Vallée Poussin's (very long) linked paper proving the first part of the Prime Number Theorem so no hope for that! As indicated Pillichshammer proves a more general formula (than the one you ask) another way. You may try this one! Of you could consider too the claim as a theorem from de la Vallée Poussin (which it really is).

Comment: many thanks! many thanks!